# How to get URL after javascript.page.open

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, referrer

I have an ASP page (I did not write it and cannot change it) that calls an ASPX page written in VB.NET (I can change it)

Here is code from the ASP page:

```
<A style="CURSOR: pointer" title="View document" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://MYSERVER/MYPAGE.aspx?param=0123456789', 'popup');">View </A>
```

So, it pops the page with a parameter, but in order to do something, MYPAGE must know what URL the request came from. Now the problem is `Request.UrlReferrer` is NULL.

how do I find out which URL the request came from?

Thank you

**EDIT:** Just making sure everyone understands - I **CANNOT** change the ASP page. It remains the same opening a new window calling the 2nd page with `onclick="javascript:window.open('https://MYSERVER/MYPAGE.aspx?param=0123456789'`. The ONLY page I can change is the 2nd page, the one that got called.

Comment: There is a javascript window.opener property you might be able to use. [see opener property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)

Comment: Is that on the ASP side? I cannot change that.

Comment: use this <body> tag on your MYPAGE.aspx ... <body onLoad="alert(self.opener.location.href);">

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on UrlReferrer since it is obtained from a header field that the browser should send, but does not in a number of cases.

The safest and best option is to get the ASP page to provide a param in the URL to identify the requestor.

If you cannot do this, another potential option is to leave the current page in place for the ASP page and create a new page for all other requests that route to the old page with an appropriate parameter to identify the source of the traffic (or vice versa).

Comment: I cannot change ASP page. I can go with a 2nd option, but this involves a lot of changes and is highly undesirable. I will keep that option as a last resort.